# How to set full calendar to a specific start date when it's initialized for the 1st time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to set the initial month to an arbitrary month when I call the function to display the calendar.

Say for example the user selects a date last june (June 2011) somewhere else and I want fullcalendar to show up with a month display of April before (April 2010). And yes, this is just to make a case, not to make sense ;-) )

I tried to call 'gotodate' before I then subsequently call the display function but this doesn't seem to work

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', currentdate);
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {left: 'prevYear,prev,today,next,nextYear',
         center: 'title', right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay' etc...}
```

Could someone eventually please provide an example how to do this properly?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have it backwards. Display the calendar first, and then call `gotoDate`.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // Options
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', currentDate);
```

Comment: hmmmm...it's working, but the logic is strange, wouldn't you agree. So I tell the calendar to go somewhere, and then I tell him: "wait a second, that's not what I meant. What I REALLY meant is THIS...Anyway, thanks a bunch for your fast asnwer, it's working fine! Stefan

Comment: That code doesn't just display the fullCalendar, it also initializes it. So think of it this way, your way was telling a calendar that didn't yet exist to display a date. This way it's saying create the calendar, then show a date. Also, if this solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as an accepted answer by clicking on the checkbox. Thanks.

Comment: The other answer (by Jammerms) is clearly better. Please reconsider which answer you accepted.

Comment: How do you get it to also highlight the date it goes to this way?

Answer (score 94):

You should use the options 'year', 'month', and 'date' when initializing to specify the initial date value used by fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
 year: 2012,
 month: 4,
 date: 25
});  // This will initialize for May 25th, 2012.
```

See the function `setYMD(date,y,m,d)` in the `fullcalendar.js` file; note that the JavaScript setMonth, setDate, and setFullYear functions are used, so your month value needs to be 0-based (Jan is 0).

**UPDATE**:  As others have noted in the comments, the correct way now (V3 as of writing this edit) is to initialize the defaultDate property to a value that is

> anything the Moment constructor accepts, including an ISO8601 date
> string like "2014-02-01"

as it uses Moment.js.  [Documentation here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/defaultDate).

Updated example:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: "2012-05-25"
});  // This will initialize for May 25th, 2012.
```

**UPDATE**: in the V5, `defaultDate` parameter has been renamed to `initialDate`.

Comment: Yeah i believe this is the 'correct' answer to this question. `year, month, date` should be used. IIRC, the answer by Brandon would load the calendar with 2x ajax calls for the events. (if using json events). Once for the initial load using default dates, then once for the 'gotoDate' event json load.

Comment: Definitely. If using json events, calling .fullCalendar('gotoDate'... would likely result in an additional ajax request.

Comment: @Jammerms since you have experience with fullcalendar, if you wouldn't mind checking my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330106/pass-date-params-into-jquery-fullcalendar. It is not getting any responses.

Comment: The docs have changed since this answer, you should now use the 'defaultDate' option

Answer (score 30):

As per machineAddict's comment, as of version 2 and later, `year, month and day` have been replaced by [`defaultDate`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/defaultDate/), which is a [Moment](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/), supporting constructors such as an `ISO 8601` date string or a Unix Epoch.

So e.g. to initialize the calendar with a given date:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: moment('2014-09-01'),
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just pass a `Date` object:
For current date:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

For specific date '2016-05-20':

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(2016, 4, 20)
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For v5 please use initialDate instead of defaultDate. Simply renamed option

eg

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     ...
     initialDate: '2020-09-02',
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had better luck with calling the `gotoDate` in the `viewRender` callback:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  firstDay: 0,
  defaultView: 'basicWeek',
  header: {
    left: '',
    center: 'basicDay,basicWeek,month',
    right:  'today prev,next'
  },
  viewRender: function(view, element) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', 2014, 4, 24 );
  }
});
```

Calling `gotoDate` outside of the callback didn't have the expected results due to a race condition.

Comment: Be sure that this approach doesn't trigger `events` twice

Comment: Doing this seemed to disable the ability to move forward and back through months by clicking the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In version 2.1.1 this works :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
// your calendar settings...
});

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', '2014-05-01');
```

Documentation about moment time/date format : http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/
Documentation about the upgrades in version 2 : https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2

Comment: How do you get it to also highlight the date it goes to this way?

Answer (score 1):

This can be used in v5.3.2 to goto a date after initialization

```
calendar.gotoDate( '2020-09-12' );
```

eg on datepicker change

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
     ...
     initialDate: '2020-09-02',
     ...
});    

$(".date-picker").change(function(){
     var date = $(this).val();
     calendar.gotoDate( date );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to load the calendar twice and you don't have a version where defaultDate is implemented, do the following:

Change the following method:

`function Calendar(element, options, eventSources) {
 ...
 var date = new Date();
 ...
}`

to:

`function Calendar(element, options, eventSources) {
 ...
 var date = options.defaultDate ? options.defaultDate : new Date();
 ...
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            headerToolbar: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
            },
            initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
            initialDate: '2020-09-12',
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            businessHours: true,
            dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [{
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2020-09-01',
            }]
        });
        calendar.render();
    });


Just simply add that particular date to initialDate key.
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code.