# FullCalendar - Highlight a particular day in week view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am newly working on [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar). Following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174744/how-to-set-full-calendar-to-a-specific-start-date-when-its-initialized-for-the) I am able to go to a specific date when selected from a datepicker on my page.

I am displaying FullCalendar in week view. My problem here is, in week view I am not able to apply the `fc-state-highlight` class on the date I have gone to. Even though the week has my required date, it is never highlighted.

However, I am able to remove the same class from the current date by using

```
$('.fc-today').removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
```

I need to add the above class to my gone-to-date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: I have posted the solution myself.**

Answer (score 6):

Ok Guys, I worked out a solution for my problem.

Following [this documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/dayRender/) on the FullCalendar site, I used the callback method `dayRender()` to solve my problem.

The above method has two parameters- `date` and `cell`. The first one stores all the days of a week in `basicWeek` view. So, given my required date is stored in a variable `reqDate`, I did something like this:

```
$('#my-div').fullCalendar({
    year: reqDate.getFullYear(),
    month: reqDate.getMonth(),
    date: reqDate.getDate(),
    dayRender: function(daysOfWeek, cell)
    {
        if(reqDate.getDate()==daysOfWeek.getDate())
        {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
        else
        {
            $(cell).removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
    }
});
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create new event during onload and prev and next button.

The function should check for the current week like,

```
$( "table.fc-agenda-days" ).hasClass( "td.fc-today" )

or

if ($("table.fc-agenda-days").find("td.fc-today").length > 0){ 
    $("table.fc-agenda-days td.fc-widget-content").addClass('fc-state-highlight');
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: Hi Sathish, I didn't quite understand your solution. Are you sure you understood my requirement?

Comment: Sathish, I have edited my post to make my requirement more clear. Anyway, I tried including your code snippet but it didn't work.

Comment: hi kumar, i had checked the fullcalendar week view from the link which u provided. By default, "fc-state-highlight" class gets applied to the current date [5/11] column, but not the whole week. I thought, you need to apply the highlighted style to whole week.  can you explain, if i am wrong.

Comment: I understand now, it seems you need to highlight some specific date, which you are moving to...

Comment: Sathish, suppose I go to the date 25 Dec 2013. Then using gotoDate, I will display that particular week in my FullCalendar (I need to use week view). But the date (25 Dec) is not highlighted (fc-state-highlight). It has a white back ground. This is where I need some help.

Comment: Sathish, I am using basicWeek. And I just posted an answer too :)

Comment: Clean solution. :) +1

Comment: Can we change color based in start and end time in agendaWeek. Any help id really appreciated. 
Thanks,