# Highlighting the selected date in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to make the selected day in FullCalender.io highlighted (similarly to how the current day is).

Following [FullCalendar - Highlight a particular day in week view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783833/fullcalendar-highlight-a-particular-day-in-week-view) I've tried the following, which basically re-renders the calendar on a click, and highlights the cell who's date matches the clicked date .

```
    dayRender: function(date, cell)
    {
        var moment = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');

        if (moment.get('date') == date.get('date'))
        {
            $(cell).addClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
        else
        {
            $(cell).removeClass('fc-state-highlight');
        }
    },
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('render');
    },
```

But it's not doing anything. :-(

Comment: put an alert and see if moment date is compared correctly

Comment: It doesn't look like dayclick is calling the render function

Comment: please mention your fullcalendar version

Comment: I'm using the latest - 2.3.1

Comment: have you tried the answer i have posted below, i hope it solves your problem

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({selectable: true})` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use this piece of code in v1.x

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $(jsEvent.target).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
   }
});
```

v2.X

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $(jsEvent.target).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
   }
});
```

CSS `.fc-state-highlight {background:red;}`

Note: this can be achived by other ways also by making use of `data-date` attribute of cell and `date` parameter of function `dayClick`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
        $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
        $("td[data-date="+date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
   }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your v2.x option and it highlights the day (although for some reason takes many clicks on some cells before they work?) but doesn't unhighlight the old cells.  So you end up with every cell looking like it's 'selected'

Comment: The last option using data-date is much more reliable with the clicks, so will use that, but it still needs to unselect all other days

Comment: Robbie i have added the required code, and you can use whichever method you feel comfortable or works for you.

Comment: Just one small item - in week view this doesn't work and the console brings up Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: td[data-date=2015-05-12T10:00:00], any ideas?

Comment: Actually I fixed this by changing to date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')

Comment: ok i added it to the answer and also the previous `.format()` would work fine for `basicWeek` but for `agendaWeek` you got the solution right.

Comment: just want to know how to use the above solution in angular typescript v12

Answer (score 3):

Building on from the other answer, this will do what you need:

```
dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    $('.fc-day').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
    });

    $("td[data-date=" + date.format() + "]").addClass("fc-state-highlight");
},
```

Answer (score 1):

v2.X

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
    $(".fc-state-highlight").removeClass("fc-state-highlight");
    $(this).addClass("fc-state-highlight");
  }
});
```

CSS `.fc-state-highlight {background:red;}`

Answer (score 1):

One quick workaround is to use `selectable`:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar'); 

calendar.fullCalendar({
  selectable: true
})
```

Even tough this option `Allows a user to highlight multiple days or timeslots by clicking and dragging` (source: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/selectable/), it has the *side effect* of highlighting the selected day if you only click on one day.