# How to set full calendar to show next month

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to display next month details on the initialise of the calendar,

For example, if this month is May, the next month June should be displayed in
calendar.

this is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var now = new Date();
  var date = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
  var d = date.getDate(),
    m = date.getMonth(),
    y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar123').fullCalendar({
    displayEventTime: false,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
      prev: "",
      next: "",
      today: 'Today',
      month: 'Month',
      week: 'Week',
      day: 'Day'
    },

    events: [{
      title: 'Team Out',
      start: new Date(y, m, d),
      backgroundColor: ('#01BC8C')
    }],
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    droppable: true
  });
});
```

what is the best way to show next month details on calendar??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set full calendar to a specific start date when it's initialized for the 1st time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174744/how-to-set-full-calendar-to-a-specific-start-date-when-its-initialized-for-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will automatically detect the current month, add 1 month to it, and use that as the default date for initial display:

```
var cal = $('#calendar123');
cal.fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: 'prev,next today'
  },
  defaultDate: moment().add(1, "months"),
});
```

See http://jsbin.com/hulobarite/1/edit?html,js,console,output for a working demo

Comment: since FullCalendar 5.0 the field is initialDate, that accepts Date object or string 
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate

`initialDate: moment().add(1, "months").toDate(),`

Comment: @snoblucha true. This answer is aimed at fullCalendar 3. I'll add a tag to the question to clarify that.

Answer (score -1):

Use default browser [input type date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).

```html
<input id="date" type="date" value="2063-10-01">
```

Like usual, won't work in ie: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: The OP asked specific about fullCalendar.

Comment: this is nothing to do with the question

Comment: Yep just like jquery and modern web dev.

Comment: I just tried to set a date after 2010 with jquery, it is saying `Fatass Error: too optimist`

Comment: At least that is a way to consistently support `i.e` +1

Comment: @Cryptopat what on earth are you talking about? Your comments make no sense and your answer is still entirely unrelated to the question about setting a default date in fullCalendar. Are you feeling OK today?

Comment: You are very kind to ask! All good, programmability! Hopefully you too! All the best anyways

Answer (score -1):

> Try this one.

```
 var cal = $('#calendar123');
 cal.fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    defaultDate: '2018-09-05',

    viewRender: function (view, element) {
        cur = view.intervalStart;
        d = moment(cur).add('months', 1);
    }
});`
```

Comment: Can you check [this](http://jsbin.com/lohataj/edit?html,js,console,output)? It seems to not working.

Comment: @MoshFeu your JSBin is using an ancient version of fullCalendar, is different from the code above, and contains a typo which, if corrected, appears to result in an infinite loop. Anyway for the "viewRender" to even run, you need at least fullCalendar 1.6.3 (as per the docs) whereas you used 1.6 for your "example".

Comment: @MoshFeu however I agree this code doesn't appear to answer the question. This does, I believe: http://jsbin.com/hulobarite/1/edit?html,js,console,output